# How to insert id and text value taken from json inside AutoCompleteTextView ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, pojo, autocompletetextview

I can't figure out how to insert the "id_county" in addition to the "county" text into the AutoCompleteTextView.

The data comes from json and it is like this:

```
[
  {
    "county": "Torino",
    "id_county": "1",
    "id_state": "118"
  },
  {
    "county": "Vercelli",
    "id_county": "2",
    "id_state": "118"
  }
]
```

I insert the text like this into the AutoCompleteTextView:

```
ArrayList<ListCounty> data = (ArrayList<ListCounty>) response.body().getListCounty();
String[] idcounty = new String[data.size()];
String[] county = new String[data.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    idcounty[i] = data.get(i).getIdCounty();
    county[i] = data.get(i).getCounty();
}

AutoCompleteTextView countyEditText = findViewById(R.id.countyEditText);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        county);
countyEditText.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here I get the selected text in the AutoCompleteTextView:

```
countyEditText.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
    String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    //String selectedItemId = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(id);
    // here is your selected item
    Log.d("APIhouse gson", selectedItem);
    //Log.d("APIhouse gson", selectedItemId);
});
```

I need to get the id_county at the time of setOnItemClickListener event, can you help me?

Comment: Save data to variable then in onClick get the position. Use the position to get item from data.

Comment: @JavierRefuerzo I thank you, could you give me an example?
So I understand in the best way, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Method using the position. Note Object should be your object.

```
//Global variable
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList()
.....
//When you get you data set to the global var
//Set data on adapter
.....
//On click get the position in the Adapter and get the Object from the list
Object object = objectList.get(position)
```

As an alternative you could set the view tag to the object or object ID. Note Object should be your object.

```
 //Set a tag on the view in the Adapter/ViewHolder
countyEditText.setTag(object)
....
//in the click listener get the object from the tag
Object object = (Object) view.getTag()
```